# A non-numeric value encountered

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this line, but i don't know what to change to skip this error

```
$media_query = '@media screen and (max-width: ' . intval( Avada()->settings->get( 'side_header_break_point' ) ) - 32 . 'px)';
```

Comment: add a **( )** between the intval and minus

Comment: @TemaniAfif You should add it as an answer, with a little explanation of course!

Comment: @JorgeCampos  it's done ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pay attention to the order of operation as :

> the dot operator has the same precedence as + and -, which can yield
>   unexpected results.

So in your case you have 'maybe' formed two strings before applying the minus operation, to avoid this you need to add parenthesis like this :

```
'(max-width: ' . (intval( Avada()->settings->get( 'side_header_break_point' ) ) - 32) . 'px)';
```

You can learn more here : http://php.net/manual/fa/language.operators.precedence.php